# Algorithm to cut the graph into a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a finite connected graph $G$, I can make a finite number of cuts on the edges to obtain a tree. What is the most efficient algorithm to perform this procedure?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: This is not a research question: it is a very classical problem for which you can find solutions in any textbook. Google Prim's algorithm or Kruskal's algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two best choices are either prim's algorithm or kruskal's algorithm. Prim's will start with a vertex $v$ and find the cheapest edge branching out from $v$, and add it to your set of edges. Now add the cheapest edge which touches exactly one of your vertices. Repeat this process until you have a spanning tree. Kruskal's algorithm requires sorting the edges beforehand, and then building a set of trees which you later reconnect. You build each tree by connecting the cheapest two vertices in your graph which are not already in the same tree, and repeat until you have them all. Both algorithms are guaranteed to produce a minimum spanning tree in linearithmic time. (If your graph is unweighted, then the preprocessing step in kruskal could be removed, and all edge selection in prim could be removed, and we would have a linear time algorithm. This is clearly optimal because it would take linear time to even read the input).

Comment: Maybe they are not the most efficient.

Comment: The OP does not seem to specify if the graph is weighted or if it is, that it's important the highest weighted edges be cut. So without those additional assumptions you could use Prims or Kruskals in linear time and this would be optimal @echo

Comment: I remember that the Kruskal's algorithm requires extra $\mathcal{O}(|E|\log|E|)$ time to sort the edges and Prim's algorithm in fact isn't linear as I found in Wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Comment: It isnt linear on a weighted graph, if you modify it slightly for an unweighted graph, you can remove the sorting step in kruskal and the edge selection step in prim, and they are linear

Comment: Make sense. You've assumed it's a unweighted graph.

Comment: Yes, or if it is weighted you could make it behave like an unweighted graph by just ignoring the weights.

Answer (score 2):

I think a depth first search is enough, which is $\mathcal{O}(|V| + |E|)$.  Both Prim's algorithm and Kruskal's algorithm in fact return a minimum spanning tree, but it seems that you only ask to return any spanning tree.